# Can a GL_FLOAT texture be assigned to a FBO as a COLOR attachment?

Tags: c++, opengl, fbo

For offscreen rendering to a texture, I'm attaching at the attachment GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 a texture defined by

> glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGBA,width,height,0,GL_RGBA,GL_FLOAT,NULL);

I then render to the FBO using a fragment shader that outputs a vec4, so normally, that should be ok. To check that I display the texture correctly, I use the function

> glTexSubImage2D()

to add some grey pixels in the middle of the texture. The texture IS correctly displayed (I can perfectly see these pixels at the right place), but the rest of the texture is only noisy artifacts (when it's not black).

Does this come from the fact that I use GL_FLOAT for a GL_RGBA texture? If yes, how can I, in GLSL, convert a uvec4 to vec4? The output of my main shader is a vec4, and I don't know how to convert the uvec4 output of a usampler2D texture to my final vec4.

Thank you for any answer you might provide :)

EDIT : I found the solution : I didn't clear the GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT between my 2 renders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this question was self-answered, but a discussion need to be had about this:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGBA,width,height,0,GL_RGBA,GL_FLOAT,NULL);
```

That does *not* create a floating-point texture. It creates a texture that contains normalized, unsigned integers.

The [actual format of a texture](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format) is the third parameter; that defines what the texture actually contains. The last three parameters define how you are trying to [upload data to the texture](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Transfer); if the pointer is NULL (and no PBO is bound), then the parameters mean *nothing*.

Comment: Oh, I got that wrong then. Thank you very much for your answer, that may explain why my shadow mapping doesn't work :)